# Knockout.js and Sammy.js wrong behaviour

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, sammy.js

I'm developing admin panel to my website and decided to do it with knockout and sammy. But I am faced with a routing problem. I have two pages:

```
http://localhost/admin/element and http://localhost/admin/category.
```

On my element page I have the following Sammy config:

```
Sammy(function() {
            this.get('#:currentpage', function() {
                self.reloadPage(this.params.currentpage);
            });

            this.get('', function() {
                this.app.runRoute('get', '#1');
            });
        }).run();
```

Everything works perfect but if I try to go to another page (by usual link, e.g. [Edit Categories](/Admin/Category)) I just get to the empty route on the same page, so I just cannot go to another page with link. Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use '' in your Sammy configuration. Try '/' for root page or '/admin/element' for your elements instead.

```
var Router = function() {
    var sammy = new Sammy.Application(function() {

            this.get('#:currentpage', function(context) {
                alert(context.params.currentpage);
            });

            this.get('/admin/element', function () {
                this.app.runRoute('get', '#1');
            });

        }),
        run = function() {
            sammy.run();
        };

    return {
        run: run
    };
};

$(function() {
    var r = new Router();
    r.run();
});
```

PS: The example uses version of Sammy 0.7.1. In version 0.6.3 there is another behavior.

Comment: Thanks, this simple suggestion helped me a lot:)

Answer (score 0):

This works if you have an action link and want to click through to another page

```
`<li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin Action Link Test", "Admin", "Home")</li>
this.get('/Home/Admin', function ()
                {
                    location.assign("/Home/Admin");
                });`
```

or you can do this using the hash

```
<li><a href="#/Home/About">About Full Path</a></li>  
this.get('#/Home/About', function ()
                {                       
                    location.assign("/Home/About");                   
                });
```